# SQL - Linked Vehicle Table on a DataGridView

Tags: sql, datagridview

Ok, so I've been looking at the site for some time, taking sound advise and using that in my development.

However, I've come across a problem which I can't seem to find the write direction to solve. I am a complete SQL beginner, so I've been scratching my head and searching Google for more time than I normally allow myself. So, I'm here to ask if there is a way to do this. I expect there is, but here goes.

I have a form built in vb.net in which user can create a vehicle record. It adds the record in Table 1. They can then add Vehicle Specs (things like Sat Nav,  Bi-Xenon Headlights, Towbar etc) from Table 2. These choices per vehicle are stored in Table 3, so that I can display within the form on my project.

The 3 tables:

**Table 1 - "Vehicles" :**

```
vehicleID ¦ RegNumber ¦ makeModel ¦ .....

        1 ¦ AB01 CDE ¦ Ford Focus ¦ .....
```

**Table 2 - "Vehicle Specifications"**

```
specID ¦ specItem

     1 ¦ Bi-Xenon Headlights

     2 ¦ Sat Nav
```

**Table 3 - "Vehicle Specifications Links"**

```
specID ¦ vehicleID¦ netCost

     1 ¦        1 ¦ 256.20 

     2 ¦        1 ¦ 150
```

Now, I've been asked to present this information in a single spread sheet so that they can send it to their end user. However, what they want is a bit jumbled up and tricky to reproduce. I can get do this by creating methods and manually producing a DataGridView, but it's slow. What I imagined better, was to create a single SQL query to do this all in one, then set the DataGridView datasource to it.

What they want is an expanding spread sheet that displays the standard information from Table 1, but also contains relevant information from Table 3 when they have allocated a spec against a vehicle.

So the result would be:

```
Make/Model ¦ Reg Number ¦ Bi-Xenon Headlights ¦ Sat Nav

Ford Focus ¦   AB01 CDE ¦              256.20 ¦ 150
```

So, should they add a Tow Bar to this vehicle, a new column would be added. Similarly, if Sat Nav was removed, the column would disappear.

If this is possible, can I ask some clever chap to steer me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cs As String = "connection string here"
Dim query As String = "SELECT table_1.makeModel, table_1.regNumber" & _
                      "INTO table_new" & _
                      "FROM table_1" & _
                      "JOIN table_2 ON table_2.vehicleID = table_1.vehicle.ID" & _
                      "JOIN table_3 ON table_2.specID = table_3.specID"
Dim newTable As New DataTable
Dim dgv As New DataGridView
Dim bs As New BindingSource

Using con As New SqlConnection(cs)
  con.Open()
  Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, con)
    adapter.Fill(newTable)
  End Using
  con.Close()
End Using

dgv.autogeneratecolumns = true
bs.DataSource = newTable
dgv.DataSource = bs
```

my vb is bastardized from my c# so its maybe close but not perfect (not tested), cheers

Comment: Unless I used your code incorrectly, which I'll apologize in advance for,this pulls the information from Table 3 very well, but it doesn't produce the desired results. The concept is to have each spec charge in individual columns (column titles) with the cost per item in the cells:
 
Make/Model ¦ Reg Number ¦ Bi-Xenon Headlights ¦ Sat Nav


Ford Focus ¦   AB01 CDE ¦              256.20 ¦ 150